# Retrieve lost digits in floating point operations

Tags: floating-point

Is there a reliable and standard way to retrieve lost mantissa in floating point operations?

I.E.

```
public float Sum(float a, float b, out float lostDigits)
{
    float sum = a + b;
    if(a > b)
        lostDigits = (sum - a) - b;
    else
        lostDigits = (sum - b) - a;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What it is your purpose? In general no, because your operations still lose precision. You may want to use high precision maths libraries (e.g. where you set the number of digits), but that could be slow (but useful to check/understand floats, or for few specific calculations).

Comment: FYI, the preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point number is “significand”, not “mantissa”. “Mantissa” is an old word for the fraction portion of a logarithm. Mantissas are logarithmic: Adding to a mantissa multiplies a number. Significands are linear: Multiplying a significand multiplies a number.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: If you have questions about the purposes of clever uses of floating-point arithmetic, then please consult a textbook such as *Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic* by Muller *et al*. Skilled practitioners use such techniques routinely in properly proven and engineered ways, in contrast to much of the amateurish information prevalent on Stack Overflow. If your question was instead intended to dissuade OP from this approach, then please stop. This is a correct approach to using floating-point arithmetic properly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I think you misunderstand my comment. The question has very few context. Now that I see the answers, I think you are right. In any case I was not dissuading. In any case, if you do it, do also a test function: unfortunately it is not seldom to have new compilers, or unexpected flag set, which cause unwanted optimization (C is stricter about float, but GCC has flag to increase optimization/ordering operations).

Comment: `if(a > b)` makes some sense if `a,b` are both positive.  A general purpose `Sum()` needs to handle other cases.

Answer (score 1):

### Fast2Sum

With a caveat explained below, the algorithm shown in the question is the *Fast2Sum* algorithm described by T.J. Dekker in 1971, although it first appeared as part of William Kahan’s “Compensated sum method” in 1965. If:

- the floating-point radix is 2 or 3,
- subnormal numbers are available,
- each operation is performed with round-to-nearest,
- each operation is performed with the same floating-point precision, and
- `sum` does not overflow to an infinity,

then the real-number sum of `sum` and `lostDigits` equals the real-number sum of `a` and `b`, per Jean-Michel Muller *et al* in *Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic*, 2010, clause 4.3.1, “The Fast2Sum algorithm.”

### Caveat

*Fast2Sum* requires that the **exponent** of `a` be at least as great as the **exponent** of `b`. Thus the test `a > b` is inadequate if `a` or `b` may be negative. `fabs(a) > fabs(b)` would suffice to ensure the *then* clause works, but it does not guarantee the *else* clause works. Instead, Muller *et al* give a *2Sum* algorithm that works for any radix and any `a` and `b` that are normal numbers and provided there is no overflow or, in radices greater than 2, underflow<sup>1</sup>:

```
s  = a  + b;
ap = s  - b;
bp = s  - ap;
ad = a  - ap;
bd = b  - bp;
t  = ad + bd;
```

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> As aka.nice notes, it does not seem like underflow would be a problem, if subnormals are supported. Since addition and subtraction do not involve any digits lower in position than those in their operands, underflow to subnormal results should not have any difference in the computations compared to the same operations scaled to avoid underflow. In this answer, I reported the statements made in Muller *et al*. It may be the code works with underflows provided subnormals are supported, but I hesitate to alter Muller *et al* without careful consideration.

Comment: In base 2, the operations will be exact if ever they underflows. I just wonder why underflow is to be cared of in other bases?

Comment: @aka.nice: I agree. Added as a footnote.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. It's the basic operation used in [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm), and is quite similar to your code. It works as follows:

```
assert(a >= b)
sum = a + b
bPrime = sum - a
resid = b - bPrime
```

`a + b` (the exact value, not the computed quantity) is now *exactly* equal to `sum + resid` (again, the exact value). Of course, you can't directly use this: computing `sum+resid` in a floating point context will just yield `sum`. The idea behind Kahan summation is to reintroduce the residual when adding subsequent terms. Other approaches simply keep values around as the implicit sum of a set of floating point numbers with non-overlapping mantissas.